# ShortestPath query is too slow with OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I am using the following code to find the shortest path between two nodes:

```
Iterable<Object> spath = orientGraph.getRawGraph().command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Object>( 
                "select shortestPath("+v1.getId()+","+v2.getId()+",'BOTH')"));
```

My problem is that I it needs too much time. My graph has 36,692 vertices and 367,662 edges and the query needs approximately 2 minutes. I use orientdb-1.6.2. My machine has a 2.3 Ghz CPU (i5), 4GB RAM and 320GB disk and I am running on Macintosh OSX Mavericks (10.9).

Note that I don't use any special configuration for my DB. I just open it with the following code:

```
orientGraph = new OrientGraph("plocal:"+orientDBDir);
```

Also my heap size is at 2GB.

Is there a way to boost up the procedure in terms of speed?

EDIT: I am trying to print the results with the following code

```
System.out.println(spath.iterator().next());
```

After some test I realised that the spate.iterator().next() line is the one that slows down the procedure. Why is that?

Comment: so you aren't using the server, but you're connected embedded to OrientDB, right? Is this a cold start? Have you tried to execute 2 times the same query to see if it's faster?

Comment: No I am not using the server. This is a cold start. I run it for 5 iterations and it doesn't get any faster.

Comment: How many elements are returned? When you display the elements, can you try to do only: System.out.println(spath.iterator().next().getIdentity());

Comment: One element, more specifically it returns this `#-2:0{shortestPath:[2]} v0 `. There is not any function named getIdentity()

Comment: so there is no reason why .next() takes so much time. Could you provide in any way the database? Another thing: try to use the explain from studio/console. Type "explan " and the query you're executing.

Comment: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lu20twfmg1wh88r/JrQuHtnNPB) is the database. I tried explain as you suggested and I get this: `Exception in thread "OrientDB MemoryWatchDog" 
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Do you have the 2 RID passed as parameter to test the same use case?

Comment: That's my command:
`explain select shortestPath(#9:0,#9:1,'BOTH')`

Comment: I tried once more and it gave my the following `Profiled command '{optimizationElapsed:0,elapsed:109165.39,resultType:collection,resultSize:1}' in 109.167000 sec(s):`
`{"@type":"d","@version":0,"optimizationElapsed":0,"elapsed":109165.39,"resultType":"collection","resultSize":1,"@fieldTypes":"optimizationElapsed=l,elapsed=f"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release 1.7-SNAPSHOT fixed this problem. Now from 2 minutes the same query returns in 0.1 seconds!